# Django return property if not null else return method result

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create a dynamic property using the method decorator, the problem I'm having is that I want to use this field if the user hasn't save his/her own only. For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name if self.name else "John"
```

Basically, I want to return "John" if I don't find anything in the name fields. However, doing it this way, Django complains because `self.name` is looking into the name function not the actual property.

`maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Is there a way to refer to the real property or maybe some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is to rename your accessor method/property:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name if self.name else "John"
```

then when you have an instance:

`person.get_name()`

Answer (score 2):

You should not duplicate names within single namespace. You can either rename your field from `name` to `_name`, since you are not going to expose it or give your property another name.

Actually, I can't see any way to get initial attribute `name`. It seems like it totally overrides by property:

```
In [8]:   1 class A(object):
          2     name = 0
          3     @property
          4     def name():
          5         return self.name or 5

In [9]: A.__dict__
Out[9]: 
<dictproxy {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
 'name': <property at 0x7f50832736d8>}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you can't use a [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default)? You can put a callable in there if you want something more interesting than a single value.

From the docs:

```
def name_default():
    return "John"

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=name_default)
```

Comment: This was going to be a great idea... I need to access self and determine what "John" is going to be like based on other fields in the object. Failed to mentioned that. +1 anyways; it would have worked well.